# Shorter notation for $\{1,...,N\}$ and $\{-N,...,N\}$

Tags: notation

Often I need to write something like $n \in \{1,...,N\}$ or $n \in \{-N,...,N\}$ in subscripts and sums. I'd like to use something a bit shorter. Looking around at all the notation questions on Math.SE I came up with the following:

$$ n \in \{1,...,N\} \rightarrow n \in \mathbb{Z}^+_{\le N}$$

$$ n \in \{-N,...,N\} \rightarrow |n| \in \mathbb{Z}_{\le N}$$

Is there any better notation I could use that is also short? Or should I just define my own notation like $\{1,...,N\} = \mathbb{Z}^N, \{-N,...,N\} = \mathbb{Z}^{|N|}$

Comment: $\Bbb Z^N$ has its own meaning already.

Comment: in context of set theory, you could also assume  $n=\{0, 1, \dotsc, n-1\}$. however zero based indexing is rather counter intuitive for most mathematicians.

Comment: @AkivaWeinbergercolumbus what about $\mathbb{Z}_N$?

Comment: @geometrikal Sometimes used as another way of writing $\Bbb Z/N\Bbb Z$ (integers modulo $N$), I _think_.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen $[n]$ to mean $\{1,\dots,n\}$. This is used, for example, in the wonderful book *generatingfunctionology.* Don't assume your readers will be familiar with it, though; you should explain your notation in the text or a footnote.

Comment: Good idea, I will make it clear at the beginning.